# How to insert list of objects in object box database in android ? Like Room database

Tags: java, android, android-room, objectbox

**I want to insert lists of objects to object box. Is that possible to do that? Just like room database in android. Any one know how to to that? or its impossible?**

example code in below:

```
notesBox = ((App) getApplication()).getBoxStore().boxFor(Note.class);
ArrayList<Note> noteList = new ArrayList<>();
notesBox.put(noteList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this works exactly as you suggest. It's also more efficient than putting each one-by-one (all objects in the list will be put inside a single transaction).

https://objectbox.io/files/objectbox-java/current/io/objectbox/Box.html#put-java.util.Collection-

https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started#basic-box-operations